# Visual Studio 2022: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm, node-modules, tsconfig

I am unable to build an angular application in Visual Studio 2022

I receive the next error:

```
TS1219  Build:Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? *experimentalDecorators* set to false, but it didn't help.
[image]

Comment: Angular is not really ready to drop entirely the `experimentalDecorators`. You need to make this a warning instead of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors were fixed by adding the next lines into the csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>commonjs</TypeScriptModuleKind>
   <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  </PropertyGroup>
```